# Removing the setTimeout interval

Tags: javascript, dom, setinterval

After loading the document, I want to refresh the page once. So I wrote this code. It is working fine, but it is calling again and again. because I am refreshing same page. but I want to clear the interval after one time execution.

```
function refreshPage(){
    document.location.reload(true);
    alert('page is refresh.');
}
var interval = setTimeout('refreshPage()', 3000);
```

Comment: What is the usage for calling one time the function on reload? . What's your goal?

Comment: some code is not working perfectly. that's what i want another refresh, then it is working fine.

Comment: @nareshkumar You should fix the problem (with our help in another question) instead of reloading the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want it to work only once, whatever the delay, you could store in localStorage the fact you did it :

```
    function refreshPage(){
        alert('page will refresh.');
        document.location.reload(true);
        localStorage['refreshDone'] = 'yes';
    }
    if (!localStorage['refreshDone']) {
        setTimeout('refreshPage()', 3000);
    }
```

But you can't simply clear the timeout or interval as the window variables are lost each time you reload the page.

As I'm not sure of your exact goal, in case you'd want to refresh if it hasn't been done recently, you could store a timestamp in localStorage :

```
    function refreshPage(){
        alert('page will refresh.');
        document.location.reload(true);
        localStorage['refresh'] = new Date().getTime();
    }
    var lastTimeRefresh = parseInt(localStorage['refresh']||'0', 10);
    if (new Date().getTime() - lastTimeRefresh > 30*60*1000) { // 30 minutes
        setTimeout('refreshPage()', 3000);
    }
```

Comment: Yes, the point is simply you can't simply use clearInterval or any window variable.

Comment: But if the browser does not supports `localStorage` the page will keep on refreshing

Answer (score 0):

You could set javascript cookies at the first refresh and then check if cookies are set or not, If it is not set please set the cookies and refresh the page, If not do nothing